# Django's DB API can't come back with all results

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm trying to list all Characters from a User, but my code only return the first Character, can someone lend me a hand?
I'm using the User class from django.contrib.auth.models package.

models.py

```
class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def sheetList(request):
    charL = get_list_or_404(Character, pk=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'sm/sheetList.html',{'charList': charL})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're filtering on the primary key, which by definition is unique. I suspect you meant to filter on the user:

```
get_list_or_404(Character, user=request.user)
```